# no. of newspapers read by students

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a college of 300 students, every student reads 5 newspaper and every newspaper is read by 60 students. Then what is the number of newspapers which are read ? I got the right answer which is 25 but i logically fail to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, assume $x_1,x_2,...x_{300}$ are students and $n_1,n_2,...$ are newspapers. Then, without loss of generality, the number of newspapers are:
$$x_1 -x_{60} \equiv n_1-n_5; \\ x_{61} -x_{120} \equiv n_6-n_{10}; \\ x_{121} -x_{180} \equiv n_{11}-n_{15}; \\ x_{181} -x_{240} \equiv n_{16}-n_{20}; \\ x_{241} -x_{300} \equiv n_{21}-n_{25}. \\ $$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the number of "readings" - the amount of times a newspaper is read. This number increases by 1 every time someone reads a newspaper.

From the perspective of students, there are 300 students who each read 5 newspapers. Therefore the number of readings is $300\times5 = 1500$.

On the other hand, from the perspective of newspapers, every newspaper is read by 60 students. The number of newspapers has to be 25, so that $25\times 60 $ is also $1500$.